# How to input password with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I'm using Jenkins to create a build for my Node.js project. I use Grunt to build my project and I use a plugin called config-leaf so that I can encrypt my Gruntfile prior to putting it in our repo since there are sensitive things in that file.

When Jenkins downloads my code, I need to be able to decrypt the file stored in Git using `npm run decrypt` to run the decryption script. I am prompted for the password by the command. How can I have Jenkins enter the password when it reaches this point?

Comment: You can try using [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to store you password in a masked form within the job.
Then if `npm run decrypt` can accept the password non-interactively you can just provide the stored password in a command line (it will be exposed by EnvInject plugin as an env var but won't appear in the logs). If a password is only allowed to be typed interactively (like in ssh) then take a look at [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Yeah it's interactive. Unfortunately, this Jenkins instance is running on windows so `expect` isn't an option.

Comment: Then [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) is for you. It's pure python and I used it once on Windows without need of mingw/cygwin/etc..